# How to display text on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm new to Xcode an trying to design a basic text app. I'm wondering what the best way to display mutable text that cannot be edited by the user. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much text you want display

1) UILabel for short things...won't be editable

2)and UITextView for large texts (set editable property to false)